# sapply, lappy, function (x), RODBC, SQLServer

Tags: r, function, loops, sapply

I'd like to use the apply functions to automate plotting of data contained in about 30 tables on SQL Server, but it doesn't work.  And is there a better way to code this?

What I want:

1. establish connection to SQL Server w/RODBC  ---this works fine
2. read each table  ---this also works fine, reading to df for example
3. exclude system id fields and character fields   ---doesn't work
4. plot numeric value fields in each table  ---works in another loop
5. write plots to pdf, one per table, one figure per table field  ---works in another loop

Example of SQL Server table structure

```
  bSystemId cSystemId lengthdecimal heightquantity desc
1      2218        58            22            184    a
2      2219        58            22            109    b
3      2220        58            22            103    c
4      2221        58            22            192    d
```

Loop code:

```
t<-sqlTables(channel, tableType ="TABLE")  # create list
t1<-list(t[,3])                            #limit list to table names only

lapply(t1,function (x)   
   {
     a<-sqlFetch(channel,x,max=20)             
     a1<-a[sapply(a,is.numeric)]             
     varlist<-names(a[,!grepl("SystemId",(a1))]) 
     pdf(file=(paste(x,".pdf")) )
     figures<-lapply(varlist,function(y) 
         {
         plot(data=a, a[,1],a[,y], xlab=names(a[1]), ylab=as.name(y))
         })
dev.off()  
   })
```

For a specific case, the code works, but not for the loop, i.e.,

```
t1<-as.data.frame(sqlFetch(channel,"tbl1"))
a<-head(t1[sapply(t1,is.numeric)])
b<-a[,!grepl("SystemId",names(a))]
```

Thanks for any comments.

For those who wanted a working example, using original code and dfs instead of read from SQL Server:

```
bSystemId<-seq(2218,2221,1)
cSystemId<-rep(58,4)
lengthdecimal<-rep(22,4)
heightquantity<-sample((100:220),4)
desc<-c("a","b","c","d")
t<-data.frame(bSystemId,cSystemId,lengthdecimal,heightquantity,desc)
s<-t*1.3

t1<-("s","t")                   
lapply(t1,function (x)   
   {
     a<-x  
     a1<-a[sapply(a,is.numeric)]             
     varlist<-names(a[,!grepl("SystemId",(a1))]) 
     pdf(file=(paste(x,".pdf")) )
     figures<-lapply(varlist,function(y) 
         {
         plot(data=a, a[,1],a[,y], xlab=names(a[1]), ylab=as.name(y))
         })
dev.off()  
   })
```

Update:

The comments are helping. Now the main block of code above generates this error:
    Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
    In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Update #2:

NAs were affecting the plot statement. The updated code:

```
 t<-sqlTables(channel, tableType ="TABLE")  # create list
 t1<-list(t[,3])                            

 lapply(t1,function (x)   
  {
    a<-sqlFetch(channel,x)
    ab<-a[is.na(a)]<- (-1)
    a1<-ab[sapply(ab,is.numeric)]
    varlist<-names(a1[,!grepl("SystemId",names(a1))])
    pdf(file=(paste(x,".pdf")) )
    figures<-lapply(varlist,function(y) 
         {
        (plot(a[,1],a[,y], xlab=names(a[1]), ylab=as.name(y)))
         })
 dev.off()  
  })
```

Update #3

Here's the final version, including a filter to exclude somesystem tables on SQL Server.  Seems to work with or without fixed = T in the apply function.

```
 t<-sqlTables(channel, tableType ="TABLE")        
 t1<-list(t[,3]) 
 t1<-t1[[1]][-c(16,18:22)]                           

 lapply(t1,function (x)   
   {
     a<-sqlFetch(channel,x, max=200)                     
     ab<-(a[sapply(a,is.numeric)])      
     a1<-ab[is.na(ab)]<- (-1)   
     varlist<-names(ab[,!grepl("SystemId",names(ab))])
     pdf(file=(paste(x,".pdf")) )
     figures<-lapply(varlist,function(y) 
         {
         (plot(ab[,1],ab[,y], xlab=names(ab[1]), ylab=as.name(y)))
         })
 dev.off()  
    })
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: `varlist` will be a logical vector, if anything, and not a list of variable names as I suspect you want.

Comment: Also you don't assign the output of `sqlFetch` to anything

Comment: Those two corrections may have fixed it.  Trying it now.

Comment: Now I'm getting a plot window error/ need finite ylim value error, and 50 warnings.   Summary of changes:  1.  assigned output of sqlFetch, 2. added parentheses to varlist statement, 3.  added 'names' to varlist statement (to pass to plot statement).  I'll keep working on it.  Thanks for any further comments.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where you are with this, but a variation on this worked for me:

```
lapply(t1,function (x)   
{
  a  <-sqlFetch(channel,x,max=20)             
  a1 <-a[sapply(a,is.numeric)]             
  varlist<-names(a[,!grepl("SystemId",names(a),fixed=T)]) 
  pdf(file=(paste(x,".pdf")) )
  figures<-lapply(varlist,function(y) 
  {
    plot(a[,1],a[,y], xlab=names(a[1]), ylab=as.name(y))
  })
  dev.off()  
})
```

I can't run this exactly as is because of the `sqlFetch`, but basically I see the following problems with your *original code*:

1. `grepl(...)` expects a regular expression as the first argument, you are passing a simple string. This is OK if you use `fixed=T`.
2. You need to apply `grepl(...)` to the column names of a, not "`(a1)`".
3. Your call to `plot(...)` should not have a `data=...' argument.

Comment: I'll try fixed = T.  I got it to write the pdfs, but I'm getting an error:  invalid factor level, NAs generated.--- Could I potentially get around this by using     stringAsFactors=FALSE?                                                                                                                   Also, I need to exclude both character fields and numeric system id fields from the plotting.  If I apply grepl() to column names of a instead of a1, will that exclude character fields?

Comment: Your code plots a[,1], which is the bSystemId field, against each of the non-systemId fields. So what do you mean you want to exclude it?

Comment: The intent is to use the first field in 'a' as the x variable in the plots, then produce a list obsevations only--no character data, no system ids, and use those as the y variable.  So that's why I used 'a1'.  Otherwise its not clear how to use a system Id in one case but not the other.

Comment: So the code above should work. Using `fixed=T` in the call to `grepl(...)` will cause `varlist` to have only those columns *not* containing the string `"SystemId"`.